# btGeneric6DofSpringConstraint not working properly

Tags: bulletphysics

I am trying to connect two bodies (one static and one dynamic) using a spring in Bullet. I am using the btGeneric6DofSpringCOnstraint.

The dynamic body hangs from the static body.

During the simulation, I am changing the mass of the dynamic body:

```
btVector3 localInertia;
btb->getCollisionShape()->calculateLocalInertia(mass,localInertia);
btb->setMassProps(mass,localInertia);
btb->updateInertiaTensor();
//m_dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(btb);
btb->activate(true);
```

However, no matter what mass I use, the body is still hanging at a same distance from the static body.

Any idea of why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the constraint is not using the new mass properties because it is not being updated, and caches some internal precomputed values. You should search a way to update the constraint but sorry I don't know if there is a solution.